# Number Keys 1-9 not working on Apple Wireless Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

How can I manually setup a passkey as "000000" (containing only zeros) to pair Bluetooth keyboard to iMac rather than the random keys generated by Mac. I'm currently using Mavericks & struggling to reconnect the keyboard as i'm unable to give the pass key other than 'zeros'. 
In the link : [Can't pair apple wireless keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64523/cant-pair-apple-wireless-keyboard), SingleShot has mentioned of a way to manually set the passkey to 'zeros'.

Comment: What is wrong with those Instruction here? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1809?viewlocale=en_US and they mean use the build in keyboard to type not the Bluetooth, since that one is not paired and not active.

Comment: In case yours isn't a duplicate, please edit the question body to explain what OS you are using and how this is materially different than the other posts in getting a bluetooth keyboard paired. We can then reopen is for answers at that point.